# Change output logfile name inside python subprocess to make it unique

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using python subprocess to email logfile to a user who runs python script. However each time user runs the script logfile gets overwritten. Here is the unix subprocess command I am using inside python code:

```
subprocess.Popen("mail -s 'logfile.log attached' -r az12@abc.com -a logfile.log $USER@abc.com &> /dev/null",shell=True)
```

How could I make logfile name unique? Maybe incremant logfile name as logfile1.log, logfile2.log and so on?

Trick is how do I achieve this inside subprocess?

Answer (score 3):

Also you can do this with datetime module:

```
import datetime
filename = "logfile-%s.log" % datetime.datetime.today().isoformat()
command = "mail -s '{0} attached' -r az12@abc.com -a {0} $USER@abc.com &> /dev/null".format(filename)
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

The name of log file will look like `logfile-2015-03-13T21:37:14.927095.log`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `timestamp` to generate a logfile name. About using that one in subprocess, command is nothing but a string. So it is as simple as

```
import time
fileName = "logfile." + str(time.time()) + ".log" # use your logic to generate logFile name.
command = "mail -s '%s attached' -r az12@abc.com -a %s $USER@abc.com &> /dev/null" %(fileName, fileName)
subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True)
```